# How to add key,value pair to dictionary?

Tags: python

How to add key,value pair to dictionary?.Below i have mentioned following format?

```
{'1_somemessage': [[3L,
                    1L,
                    u'AAA',
                    1689544L,
                    datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 22, 30),
                    u'gffggf'],
                   [3L,
                    1L,
                    u'BBB',
                    1689544L,
                    datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 20, 30),
                    u'ffgffgfg'],
                   [3L,
                    1L,
                    u'CCC',
                    1689544L,
                    datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 22, 30),
                    u'hjhjhjhj'],
                   [3L,
                    1L,
                    u'DDD',
                    1689544L,
                    datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 21, 45),
                    u'jhhjjh']],
 '2_somemessage': [[4L,
                    1L,
                    u'AAA',
                    1689544L,
                    datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 22, 30),
                    u'gffggf'],
                   [4L,
                    1L,
                    u'BBB',
                    1689544L,
                    datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 20, 30),
                    u'ffgffgfg'],
                   [4L,
                    1L,
                    u'CCC',
                    1689544L,
                    datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 22, 30),
                    u'hjhjhjhj'],
                   [4L,
                    1L,
                    u'DDD',
                    1689544L,
                    datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 21, 45),
                    u'jhhjjh']]}
```

Answer (score 161):

Add a key, value pair to dictionary

```
aDict = {}
aDict[key] = value
```

What do you mean by dynamic addition.

Comment: Thanks it's working..I meant resultset of query. Do you know which are the concerns using python..i don't know am new of this technology before i have worked in dotnet.

Comment: @Krishnasamy: If you have earlier worked on dotnet, Python will be a pleasure to work with. It is as versatile as dotnet and java, if not more

Comment: If I use this in for loop than its giving only last record.. how to get all key value pair in loop

Answer (score 83):

For quick reference, all the following methods will add a new key 'a' if it does not exist already or it will update the existing key value pair with the new value offered:

```
data['a']=1  

data.update({'a':1})

data.update(dict(a=1))

data.update(a=1)
```

You can also mixing them up, for example, if key 'c' is in data but 'd' is not, the following method will updates 'c' and adds 'd'

```
data.update({'c':3,'d':4})
```

Comment: Why is the down vote? The answer is trying to add useful info so viewers can have an alternative answer which IMHO is more comprehensive, could the gentleman/women who down voted pls clarify?

Comment: You don't need to answer this question since its a duplicate - the appropriate way of handling it is by flagging it as a dupe - see more info there [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Comment: @Zhenhua I found this answer useful upvoted.

Comment: This answer is much more helpful than the other ones.

Comment: SO really needs to figure out a way to make things surface better. This is down voted for being a duplicate. But it's the first thing that appears when a user searches. The down vote then starts more conversation, which causes this answer to FURTHER rise in popularity, thereby hiding the original answer. 

I would have never have found the original answer had this one not existed. So why not just delete this qeustion completely?

Comment: I think what would have made this a truly useful answer would be a discussion of the differences in the different statements - is one preferred for a given use case?  Are they all the same?  Any pitfalls to any of them?

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure what you mean by "dynamic". If you mean adding items to a dictionary at runtime, it is as easy as `dictionary[key] = value`.

If you wish to create a dictionary with key,value to start with (at compile time) then use (surprise!)

```
dictionary[key] = value
```

Answer (score 7):

I got here looking for a way to add a key/value pair(s) as a group - in my case it was the output of a function call, so adding the pair using `dictionary[key] = value` would require me to know the name of the key(s).

In this case, you can use the update method:
`dictionary.update(function_that_returns_a_dict(*args, **kwargs)))`

Beware, if `dictionary` already contains one of the keys, the original value will be overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

May be some time this also will be helpful

```
import collections
#Write you select statement here and other things to fetch the data.
 if rows:
            JArray = []
            for row in rows:

                JArray2 = collections.OrderedDict()
                JArray2["id"]= str(row['id'])
                JArray2["Name"]= row['catagoryname']
                JArray.append(JArray2)

            return json.dumps(JArray)
```

Example Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 14
        "Name": "someName1"
    },
    {
        "id": 15
        "Name": "someName2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a new record in the form

```
newRecord = [4L, 1L, u'DDD', 1689544L, datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 21, 21, 45), u'jhhjjh']
```

to `messageName` where `messageName` in the form `X_somemessage` can, but does not have to be in your dictionary, then do it this way:

```
myDict.setdefault(messageName, []).append(newRecord)
```

This way it will be appended to an existing `messageName` or a new list will be created for a new `messageName`.

Comment: Alternately you can start with a `defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score -2):

To **insert/append** to a dictionary

```
{"0": {"travelkey":"value", "travelkey2":"value"},"1":{"travelkey":"value","travelkey2":"value"}} 

travel_dict={} #initialize dicitionary 
travel_key=0 #initialize counter

if travel_key not in travel_dict: #for avoiding keyerror 0
    travel_dict[travel_key] = {}
travel_temp={val['key']:'no flexible'}  
travel_dict[travel_key].update(travel_temp) # Updates if val['key'] exists, else adds val['key']
travel_key=travel_key+1
```